# boto3 ecs client pagination issue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs

I am trying to list all services in aws ECS cluster using python boto3, it can only list 100 services maximum. So trying with pagination API.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')

client = session.client('ecs')

paginator = client.get_paginator('list_services')


resp = paginator.paginate( cluster='test')

for i in resp:
  print resp
```

I tried to loop with `resp` but it does not list all services.. It does provide `nextToken` in the resp.

Any idea how to use that `nextToken` and get all services in a ECS cluster using python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flaw in your loop. Fix it to:

```
for i in resp:
  print i
```

One way to do what you are asking using nextToken:

```
resp = paginator.paginate( cluster='test')
print resp
while 'nextToken' in resp:
  resp = paginator.paginate( cluster='test', nextToken=resp['nextToken'])
  print resp
```

Comment: I am actually using `print i` in that for loop, thats typo while posting the question..

Comment: @Pasha then the solution I posted should work or you can tweak it to your needs.